# Eloquent ORM single item collection return as array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Code: `$account->deals`

This like returns an object or an array of objects.

object: `{deal}`

Array of Objects: `[{deal}, {deal}, {deal}]`

Is there a way to force the call to return an "array of objects" even if it is only returning one object?

To clarify, I do not want to use a `foreach`, `is_array()`, `count()`, etc...

this is the end product I am looking to have work: `$deals = array_merge($account->deals, $user->deals);` even when Eloquent only returns one object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out!

`$deals = array_merge($account->deals->all(), $user->deals->all());`

Hope this helps someone out in the fugure

Answer (score 1):

Collection object in laravel has method toArray() to represent collection of objects as multi-dimentional array (array of arrays). Try this:

```
$deals = $account->deals->toArray();
```

Comment: this forces an object to become an array, not an array of objects to be returned.

Comment: Please, read thoughtfully. My example was referring to Collection object. If deals() is represents a relationship (hasMany), dynamic property 'deals' will return a collection of deals for account and it could be transformed to array of deal arrays by calling toArray() method.

Comment: michaelcurry, your solution is more fast and sufficient in topic context.